# I want unique region with respective countries from the arrays of objects in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have below array of objects JSON.
It contains regions value with regCountry with multiple occurrences of both keys.

```
let arrOfObj = [
      {
        "regCountry": "Germany",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Germany",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Spain",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Spain",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Italy",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Austria",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "India",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "India",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "China",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Japan",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Congo",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Egypt",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Egypt",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
    ]
```

In above JSON you can see region value is duplicate with country also. I want unique region with list of unique countries under that region. Please check below output need :-

```
[
  {
    region: "Europe",
    countries: ["Germany", "Spain", "Italy", "Austria"]
  },
  {
    region: "Asia",
    countries: ["India", "China", "Japan"]
  },
  {
    region: "Africa",
    countries: ["Congo","Egypt"]
  }
]
```

I have tried some ways but it fails. Using .map and .filter but didn't get proper solution.
Help me to get this solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arrOfObj = [ ... ];

let result = arrOfObj.reduce((acc, { regCountry, region }) => {
  let existingRegion = acc.find(item => item.region === region);

  if (!existingRegion) {
    acc.push({ region, countries: [regCountry] });
  } else if (!existingRegion.countries.includes(regCountry)) {
    existingRegion.countries.push(regCountry);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

The `reduce` function is used to iterate over the `arrOfObj` array and accumulate the result in the `acc` variable. The second argument to reduce is a function that takes the accumulator and the current object as parameters.

Inside the `reduce` function, `acc.find` is used to check if there is already an entry for the current region in the accumulator. If not found, a new region object is created and pushed into the accumulator.

The country `obj.regCountry` is then added to the region's countries array if it's not already present. The final result is the array of unique regions with their respective lists of unique countries.

```js
let arrOfObj = [
      {
        "regCountry": "Germany",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Germany",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Spain",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Spain",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Italy",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Austria",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "India",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "India",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "China",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Japan",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Congo",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Egypt",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Egypt",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
    ]

let result = arrOfObj.reduce((acc, { regCountry, region }) => {
  let existingRegion = acc.find(item => item.region === region);

  if (!existingRegion) {
    acc.push({ region, countries: [regCountry] });
  } else if (!existingRegion.countries.includes(regCountry)) {
    existingRegion.countries.push(regCountry);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses reduce to build objects containing unique strings, then maps into the structure you want:

```js
const regionCountries = arrOfObj.reduce((accum, obj) => {
    const countries = accum[obj.region] || {};
    countries[obj.regCountry] = true;
    accum[obj.region] = countries;
    return accum;
}, {});

const result = Object.entries(regionCountries)
    .map(([k, v]) => ({
        region: k, 
        countries: Object.keys(v)
    }));

console.log(result);

// Outputs
// [ { region: 'Europe', countries: [ 'Germany', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'Austria' ] },
//   { region: 'Asia', countries: [ 'India', 'China', 'Japan' ] },
//   { region: 'Africa', countries: [ 'Congo', 'Egypt' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A relative simple solution can be crafted by using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as lookup that contains the countries by region.

We can iterate through the array of objects. Check if there is a registration for a given region. If it's not present we create the registration and assign it a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to hold the country names. Sets are designed to store unique values, if you add a value more than once it will simply be ignored.

```js
const countriesByRegion = new Map();
for (const { region, regCountry } of arrOfObj) {
  if (!countriesByRegion.has(region)) countriesByRegion.set(region, new Set());
  countriesByRegion.get(region).add(regCountry);
}
```

After we've iterated all the object, we can convert our `Map` instance into an array with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). By passing a second argument we can map the region/counties pair into the desired format.

```js
const desired = Array.from(countriesByRegion,
  ([region, countries]) => ({ region, countries: [...countries] })
);
```

If you don't mind `countries` being a `Set` rather than an `Array`, the above can be simplified because we don't need the set to array conversion.

```js
const desired = Array.from(countriesByRegion, ([region, countries]) => ({ region, countries }));
```

```js
function runSolution(arrOfObj) {

  const countriesByRegion = new Map();
  for (const { region, regCountry } of arrOfObj) {
    if (!countriesByRegion.has(region)) countriesByRegion.set(region, new Set());
    countriesByRegion.get(region).add(regCountry);
  }
  const desired = Array.from(countriesByRegion,
    ([region, countries]) => ({ region, countries: [...countries] })
  );
  
  console.log(desired);
}

runSolution([
  { regCountry: "Germany", region: "Europe" },
  { regCountry: "Germany", region: "Europe" },
  { regCountry: "Spain",   region: "Europe" },
  { regCountry: "Spain",   region: "Europe" },
  { regCountry: "Italy",   region: "Europe" },
  { regCountry: "Austria", region: "Europe" },
  { regCountry: "India",   region: "Asia"   },
  { regCountry: "India",   region: "Asia"   },
  { regCountry: "China",   region: "Asia"   },
  { regCountry: "Japan",   region: "Asia"   },
  { regCountry: "Congo",   region: "Africa" },
  { regCountry: "Egypt",   region: "Africa" },
  { regCountry: "Egypt",   region: "Africa" },
]);
```

This answer uses [object/array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), the [property definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions), and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this via below method by my own. Thanks for other answers also.

```js
let arrOfObj = [
      {
        "regCountry": "Germany",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Germany",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Spain",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Spain",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Italy",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Austria",
        "region": "Europe"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "India",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "India",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "China",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Japan",
        "region": "Asia"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Congo",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Egypt",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
      {
        "regCountry": "Egypt",
        "region": "Africa"
      },
    ]
const uniqueRegions = (arrOfObj.map(item => item.region).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)).sort();
  const regionJurisdictionArr = [];
  uniqueRegions.forEach(regionName => {
    const filtered = arrOfObj.filter(row => row.region === regionName);
    const uniCountry = (filtered.map(item => item.regCountry).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)).sort();
    regionJurisdictionArr.push({region:regionName, countries:uniCountry});
  });
  console.log(regionJurisdictionArr);
```